# Extension of multiplication to the tensor algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, tensor-products, graded-modules

In this wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra#Construction

> > We construct $T(V)$ as the direct sum of vector spaces $T^kV$ for $k=0,1,2,…$
> >     $$ T(V)= \bigoplus_{k=0}^\infty T^kV = K\oplus V \oplus (V\otimes V) \oplus (V\otimes V\otimes V) \oplus \cdots$$
> >     The multiplication in $T(V)$ is determined by the canonical isomorphism
> >     $T^kV \otimes T^\ell V \to T^{k + \ell}V$
> >     given by the tensor product, which is then extended by linearity to all of $T(V)$.

My question is about the last sentence : "which is then extended by linearity to all of $T(V)$".

What does this sentence mean? i thought that the multiplication given above covers all $T(V)$ and does not need to be extended since any element in $T(V)$ is a tensor product of $k$ elements of $V$ and hence it belongs to $T^kV$!! thank you for your help.

Comment: An element in $T(V)$ is a linear combination of elements in each degree, for example $w = v \otimes v + v \otimes v \otimes v$. Extending by linearity appears when you try to calculate $w \otimes w$.

Comment: Ok so it seems to me that "extension by linearity" is just onother name for what we know as "distributivity" of the multiplication $T^kV\otimes T^lV\rightarrow T^{k+l}V$ over addition.

Comment: Indeed. The idea is that there is a unique linear map $TV\otimes TV\to TV$ which restricts to the given maps $T^kV\otimes T^kV\to T^{k+l}V$ for all $k$, $l\geq0$.